# Kartik Yii2 Typeahead Widget event listener not working

Tags: events, yii2, twitter-typeahead

I have a Kartik Yii2 typeahead widget in my view:

```
echo \kartik\typeahead\Typeahead::widget([
    'name' => 'serial_product',
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Product Name / SKU / Serial Number / Coupon Code',
        'autofocus' => "autofocus",
        'id' => 'serial_product'
    ],
    'scrollable' => TRUE,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'highlight' => TRUE,
        'minLength' => 3
    ],
    'dataset' => [
        [
            'remote' => [
                'ttl' => 0,
                'url' => Url::to(['invoice/ajaxgetinventoryitemsnew']) . '?search=%QUERY',
                'ajax' => ['complete' => new \yii\web\JsExpression("function(response){jQuery('#serial_product').removeClass('loading');checkresult(response.responseText);return true}")]
            ],
            'limit' => 10
        ]
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "typeahead:selected" => "function(obj, item) { checkresult2(item); return true; }",
        "typeahead:render" => "function() { console.log('Whatever...'); }",
    ],
]);
```

The first "pluginEvents" (typeahead:selected) is getting triggered as it should.
The 2nd one "typeahead:render" is not triggered, and no error on the console.

Why is the render event not triggered?

Versions: typeahead.js 0.10.5 | Kartik Typeahead.php 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: use kartik\widgets\Typeahead

```
$data = [
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 
    'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
    'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana'
];

// Usage with ActiveForm and model (with search term highlighting)
echo \$form->field(\$model, 'state_3')->widget(Typeahead::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true],
    'dataset' => [
        [
            'local' => $data,
            'limit' => 10
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code in my project.

```
use kartik\typeahead\Typeahead;

<?= $form->field($model, 'country')->widget(Typeahead::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Начните ввод страны'
    ],
    'dataset' => [
        [
            'local' => $countries,
            'limit' => 10
        ]
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "typeahead:selected" => "function(obj, item) { 
            console.log(item); return true; }",
        "typeahead:render" => "function() { 
            console.log('Whatever...'); }",
    ],
    ]);  
?>
```

It works well. Any time I type a char console responses "Whatever...". "Selected" event works as well.

Maybe your code doesn't work as you expect because of **checkresult2(item)** function.